# How to create table in MyEclipse Derby

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse, derby

where i can make the table when making sample program of Hibernate with MyEclipse Derby

Answer (score 1):

From the [MyEclipse Derby Database Server Tutorial](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/derby/) (and I warmly recommend reading it entirely):

> #### Connecting to Derby with the Database Explorer
>
> Switch to the **MyEclipse Database
>   Explorer** perspective.   Please make
>   sure Derby, is started and running
>   before you attempt to connect to it.
>   In the **DB Browser** view, right
>   click the **MyEclipse Derby** driver
>   and then select **Open connection...**
>   to connect.
>
> **Note:** If you do not see the MyEclipse Derby driver, see **Restore
>   MyEclipse Derby Driver** in the
>   following section.
>
> You may use the embedded Derby
>   database just like you would any other
>   database in MyEclipse. For further
>   details, refer to the [Database
>   Explorer](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/dbexplorer/index.html) tutorial.
>
> MyEclipse Derby ships with a sample
>   database named **myeclipse**. This
>   database includes two sample schemas,
>   CLASSICCARS and MYBLOG. Other schemas
>   visible are Derby's system schemas.
>
> [image] [image]
>
> <sub>Figure 6. Connecting to Derby
>   using the MyEclipse Derby driver</sub>

Comment: @lisak *The community* decided, not me. Just don't do that or delete your answer (no, your answer wasn't relevant) and it won't happen. I'm sorry for you but I don't feel guilty for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1.For creating table in `MyEclipse Derby` first of all select open perspective in `MyEclipse IDE` at top right corner, image shown below:

[image: MyEclipse Database Explorer Showview]

2. Right click on `MyEclipse Derby` and click `Open connection`
3. Right `click on Connected to MyEclipse Derby [classiccars]` and click on `New SQL Editor`, image shown below:

[image: Connnected to MyEclipse Derby]

4. In **Editor** window write the code shown below:

`CREATE TABLE APP.EMPINFO
(EMP_ID INT NOT NULL, FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(20), MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(20), LASTNAME VARCHAR(20), 
DATEOFBIRTH DATE NOT NULL, EMAIL VARCHAR(50), ATTACHMENT VARCHAR(5000), PHONENO integer, 
ADDRESS VARCHAR(256), PINCODE integer, CONSTRAINT EMPID_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID));`

Here `APP` is schema name and `EMPINFO` is table name.

How to create table in MyEclipse Derby is shown in New SQL Editor:

[image: How to create table in MyEclipse Derby]